# Application of Options for Graphics

Tags: graphics

I have the code

```
Graphics[{Dashed, Green, Circle[{0, 0}, .4], Black, 
  Circle[{0, 0}, .5], FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}]
```

Which gives the output

[image]

However, I do not want the outer circle to be dashed. The documentation example suggests that the options are only applied to the first object after those options. So why is Dashed[] being applied to the outer circle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Nested lists of graphics constructs can be given. Directive specifications such as [`GrayLevel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GrayLevel) remain in effect only until the end of the list that contains them.

So, include [`Dashed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dashed) and the first circle in a nested list:

```
Graphics[{Green, {Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, .4]}, Black, Circle[{0, 0}, .5],
FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: And how would one know beforehand wheter or not to use a nested list with a certain option?

Comment: @pmac Directives in a list persist until the end of the list. I think that should be clear enough?

Comment: I see how that works for most of the cases. But if my list is {Green, Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, .4], Black, Circle[{0, 0}, .5], 
 FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]} then I get a solid rectangle. But according to that rule shouln't it be dashed?